# Redirect Page In Chrome Without Confirmation Dialog

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, redirect

I'm having an issue with JavaScript, especially in Google Chrome, where, when I redirect to another page, I receive a Confirm Navigation dialog asking if I want to leave or stay on the current page. In my code I'm calling a`location.replace();` method.

My goal is to bypass Chrome's Confirm Navigation dialog and, at the same time, avoid breaking the Back button in the redirection process. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: did u try `window.onbeforeunload=null;`, also you cant control back button

Comment: Ah, there's my solution. I have now added that into my code and it works. Thank you immensely, Royi!

Comment: Thanks for this! I learned that it does not work with window.location.href="url" style of redirection.

Answer (score -1):

Try using `window.location.href="your url"` [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/C9YLb/)